# Removing silence and no movement from videos

Tags: editing, video-editor

Using Windows 7, which program helps me

1. Remove silence, like the option in adobe audition
2. Remove still images in video, when nothing happens

in the same program?

Both functions should require a threshold value to distinguish between silence and non-silence and still image and non-still image.

Goal is when silence was removed these parts are removed in the video aswell, so audio and video remain in sync. Maybe a fade between frames then.

Comment: There is an answer to the similar question, but without the audio issue at http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/how-can-i-automatically-remove-pauses-from-a-video

Comment: `ffmpeg` with `-vf mpdecimate` won't shorten the audio, and will produce a variable-frame-rate output.  You could remux it to alter the frame timing, e.g. so all the frames came at fixed intervals, effectively removing the gaps.  IDK how to approach the problem of doing this while keeping audio sync.

Comment: This question (http://superuser.com/questions/818342/strip-motion-events-from-file) has an answer that uses `-vf "mpdecimate,setps='N/(5*TB)'"` to skip no-motion parts.  (output is CFR, but with only frames that have motion).  It still doesn't handle audio.