# How can I automatically remove pauses from a video?

Tags: video-editor

I have dozens of video files containing scenes of movement interspersed with 5-10 second periods of nothing happening (many identical frames in a row). There's no audio track and I'd like to strip the identical frames to remove those pauses and keep only the movement.

Is there a (preferably free) tool to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished with the `mpdecimate` filter in the free program ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -vf "mpdecimate" "out.mp4"`

Comment: Welcome to AVP and thanks for sharing what you found to address the situation.

Comment: Left a note on a similar, but different question: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/removing-silence-and-no-movement-from-videos